# Django Python 'Customer' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
class Customer(models.Model):

cust_firstname=models.TextField(max_length=50)
cust_lastname=models.TextField(max_length=50)
cust_company=models.TextField(max_length=100)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
cust_contact_number = models.IntegerField()
cust_email = models.TextField(max_length=100)
cust_address=models.TextField(max_length=200,default=None)

class Employee(models.Model):

employee_firstname = models.TextField(max_length=50)
employee_lastname = models.TextField(max_length=50)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
employee_contact_number = models.IntegerField()
employee_email = models.TextField(max_length=100)
employee_designation = models.TextField(max_length=50)
employee_address=models.TextField(max_length=200, default=None)

class ProjectDetails(models.Model):

customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee)
project_name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
project_startdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, default=None)
project_status = models.TextField(default="Initial")
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The above code is my model declaration
and my Serializer class is

```
from ProjectTemplate.models import Customer, Employee, ProjectDetails
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomerSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Customer
    fields =           ('id','cust_firstname','cust_lastname','cust_company','created_at','updated_at','cust_contact','cust_email','cust_address')

    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Employee
    fields = ('id','employee_firstname','employee_lastname','created_at','updated_at','employee_contact','employee_email','employee_designation','employee_address')

    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

class ProjectDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
customer = CustomerSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)
employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
class Meta:
        model = ProjectDetails
        fields = ('id','project_name','project_startdate','created_at','updated_at','project_status','customer','employee')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

In my view i have the below code

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = ProjectDetails.objects.all()
        projectid = self.request.query_params.get('pk', None)
        if projectid is not None:
            queryset = queryset.get(id=projectid)
            serializer = ProjectDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            serializer = ProjectDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

And my URL for the above view is

```
url(r'^api/v1/projects/$', ProjectListView.as_view()),
```

And when i  try to access the URL on my Browser i get TypeError. Im trying to get all the Customers and Employees who belong to a project. But it fails can any one help me to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to get all the Customers and Employees who belong to a project.

I am not sure what do you want to achieve here because looking at your model, an instance of `ProjectDetail` will only have one `customer` and one `employee`:

```
class ProjectDetails(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

Considering this, using `many=True` doesn't make any sense in the serializer. So this is what causing the error:

```
class ProjectDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)
    employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

---

**UPDATE:** To show a specific field from the related object:

Based on the comments in the answer the OP want to show the `name` of customer or employee instead of `id`.

It can be achieved using a [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class ProjectDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='cust_firstname', read_only=True)
    employee = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='employee_firstname ', read_only=True)
    # other fields
```

Do note that using `SlugRelatedField` you can get only one field as in the example above you would get `firstname` for both.

Comment: I get all the Projects along with Customer ID and Employee ID but i want to display Customer Name and Employee name  instead of Customer ID and  Employee ID. for that i trying to get all the fields of customer and employee so im using many=True.

Comment: `many=True` is used for a `ManyToManyField` and not for the `ForeignKey`. Please look at the updated answer in case you just need to get the name.

Comment: in case if i want all the fields of customer and employee along with the Project as my json response. Should i change customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee) to ManytoMany

Comment: If you want all the fields then just removing `many=True` from original solution would work.

Comment: I am glad to help.

Comment: When i try to save an object one of the column is getting {u'name': u'Initial'} stored. Im Passing "Initial" as my json data but the entire json string is getting stored do you have any idea.